# IdentityServer4 - user permissions on the API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, permissions, identityserver4

I'm currently setting up a new project with a Web API and a MVC UI (will eventually have a mobile UI as well which can talk to the same API).

So, I have the following plan:

1. User navigates to the MVC UI which takes them off to the IdentityServer4 server to log in or sign up
2. IdentityServer user is then added to the applications own user table in the database
3. Permissions can then be set on the user to limit their access

This means the identity server is just that, an identity server (and means I allow people to log in through Google, etc. without worrying about their roles and permissions).

So, to achieve the above, I need to check the user's permission on the API, NOT on the client (the client could be anything - web, phone app, JavaScript client, etc. so we can't rely on that to handle user permissions).

On the API, I have implemented a Permissionhandler and PermissionRequirement authorization policy. So, on the API controller or method, I can do something like: [Authorize(Policy = "CreateUser")]. It looks like I'll need to have a policy per system permission.

So in the authorisation handler I need to:

1. Get the current user's username
2. If they exist in the app database, check their permissions and auth or deny
3. If they don't exist in the app database, add them, then we can set their permissions later from the admin panel

This was going well up until I tried to request the user's username from the identity server. I understand I need to use the UserInfoClient to do that, but I can't figure out how to use the user's token/credentials to get their claims from the identity server or to at least get their User.Identity.Name.

Now I could just use the sub ID to add the user to the application database, but then whoever's managing the permissions would have no idea who that person is, so I need to use their email really.

Now in the MVC client, I can see User.Identity.Name without any problems, but in the API that value is null!?

So my question is: how on earth do I get the current user's Identity.Name, username or email from within the API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Think I've cracked it now.

```
            var mvcContext = context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext;
        if (mvcContext != null)
        {
            // Use the UserInfo endpoint to get the user's claims
            var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost:5000");
            var doc = await discoveryClient.GetAsync();

            var accessToken = await mvcContext.HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

            var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(doc.UserInfoEndpoint);
            var response = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(accessToken);

            var claims = response.Claims;
        }
```

This is detailed right at the bottom of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies so according to Microsoft, it's the right way.

You did however spark this idea, thank you Win. I had been staring at this bloody thing for hours. All you need sometimes is someone else to say something, anything, and the curse is broken! :)

I am still open to a better way of achieving this, if anyone has one.

Cheers

Comment: You are welcome. +1 and thank you for sharing so I also learn something.

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar, and was extremely disheartened to find only RBAC examples with the identity server providing the `role` claim. This seemed wrong to me too. The application should determine what permissions a user has, and compare that against what the client is requesting. Just because a client has received consent from a user, doesn't mean that user actually has permission to perform the requested action. My only question with your approach would be, what if the user changes their email address or other claim with identity - how would that get updated at application level

Comment: @crush that's a good point and not something I've got round to figuring out yet (the project I was working on isn't going ahead anymore).  Maybe it's something we don't need to worry about. Some people have different emails for different services so should we care if they change their email on the IdentityServer?  If we do care, then we can just set up the profile editor to pass relevant changes to the IdentityServer? Those are my initial thoughts anyway.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for the reply. My opinion is that the identity server should be somehow ignorant of the resource server(s). I mean, it knows they exist, but doesn't know where they exist or how to contact them. I've been having some internal debates with colleagues about who should own the data like "first, last, display name", and if an application-local version of that data should exist, or if it should always ask the identity server for it. It's easy to get it out of claims for the current user, but what about other users? I'll try to add a new comment if I come up with a "good" solution

Comment: @Craig are you injecting context into your controller? When I went to use this code my controller had no idea what context was to get .Resource from. I can access httpContext.authentication.GetTokenAsync() straight away. So where does context come from

Answer (score 2):

I believe you already configure ***IdentityServerAuthentication*** in ***Web API*** similar like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/IdentityExample/blob/master/src/IdentityServerWebAPI/Startup.cs#L24) -

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   ...
   app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
   {
      Authority = "http://UrlOfIentityServer",
      RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
      ApiName = "exampleapi"
   });
   ...
}
```

When you make a web service call, you will need to pass the same ***token*** received from ***IdentityServer*** like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/IdentityExample/blob/master/src/IdentityServerWebSite/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L34) -

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
   string accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

   httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://UrlOfWebAPI");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

   return await httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/clock/time");
}
```

Comment: I have my authorization handler in another layer of my application (i.e. another project), so I don't  have access to the HttpContext in that way. I can get to the AuthorizationHandlerContext, but not sure I can get to the HttpContext? I may be wrong.